# Multiple inputs outputting a single object

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to update an object that represents CSS grid layout. There are two methods of input that I want to support. You can either type your grid format as a string or you can use a combination of a number input and a drop down of units. What I currently have does not allow me to type in the string. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Boussadrja suggestion of adding the lazy modifier to the model does resolve the issue, but I was wondering if it would be possible to update as you type and not and exit of the field?

```
<template>
  <div class="testing">
    {{grid}}
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="input-add-column-text" v-model="columnsString">
    </div>
    <div v-for="(column, index) in grid.columns" v-bind:key="'column_' + index">
      <input type="number" min="0" step="0.25" v-model.number="column.value">
      <select name="" id="" v-model="column.unit">
        <option v-for="(option, index) in unitOptions" v-bind:value="option.value" v-bind:key="index">{{ option.text }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from 'lodash'

export default {
  name: 'testing',
  data: () => ({
    grid: {
      columns: [
        { value: 1, unit: 'fr' },
        { value: 1, unit: 'fr' },
        { value: 1, unit: 'fr' },
        { value: 1, unit: 'fr' }
      ]
    },
    unitOptions: [
      { text: 'fr', value: 'fr' },
      { text: 'px', value: 'px' },
      { text: '%', value: '%' },
      { text: 'em', value: 'em' },
      { text: 'auto', value: 'auto' },
      { text: 'min-content', value: 'min-content' },
      { text: 'max-content', value: 'max-content' },
      { text: 'minmax', value: 'minmax' }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    columnsString: {
      get: function () {
        let columnsString = ''

        for (let column of this.grid.columns) {
          columnsString += column.value + column.unit + ' '
        }

        return columnsString
      },
      set: function (newValue) {
        let columnValues = newValue.match(/[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g).map(Number)
        let columnUnits = newValue.match(/(fr|px|%|em|auto|min-content|max-content|minmax)/g).map(String)

        this.grid.columns = _.zipWith(columnValues, columnUnits, function (a, b) {
          let columns = {
            value: a,
            unit: b
          }

          return columns
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `allow me to type in the string`

Comment: Boussadrja, I have the inputs with the IDs "input-add-row-text" and "input-add-column-text". I want those inputs to update the grid object based on the text entered and also stay updated when you make changes using the number input and drop downs. Does that make sense?

Comment: i could not figure out your specific problem, i test your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zxrxjxxq44) and it looks work properly

Comment: It's that very first input. If you start typing in it, it behaves wierd.

Comment: ah ok, i had seen that, so i suggest to use `lazy` modifier to submit the changes when you leave the input

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a try. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you're welcome i'll post as answer if you want